# zsh autocompletition on alias not working

Tags: autocomplete, zsh, zshrc

I have written this simple autocompletition function for my script:

```
alias activate=". ~/.activate.sh"
_activate() { _files -W ~/Projects; }
compdef _activate activate
```

It works if I comment out the alias-line, but otherwise I get the following autocompletition:

```
activate P
Pictures/  Projects/  Public/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was quite simple, adding the following to my .zshrc solved the problem:

```
setopt complete_aliases
```